Praying for Conversion will be right?
Actually me and my girlfriend are in a relationship from 7 months. But the problem is we are from different religions.  We can't lose eachother. As I know I worship the True God Jesus.
According to the bible, Can i Ask God to Reveal Himself to her, Change her and save her so I can marry her?
Can it be true??? Does the bible approve this kinda prayer?

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=can+i+pray+for+unbelievers ...of course you can! But you should also talk to your GF, explain your faith, and why you believe, because God often acts through people, and you seem to have an "inside track".

Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Hello, John, welcome! Do give some time to the [tour] when you get a chance. This Question, like your previous one, is likely to be closed as opinion based (see Nigel's comment). Personalized advise is off topic here.

Well, I think this question has an easy answer, but first lets look at what the Scriptures say about being in a relationship with someone that is unsaved. 2 Corinthians 6:14:

Be ye not unequally yoked together with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with unrighteousness? and what communion hath light with darkness?

This verse indicates that Christians should not be involved in a marriage relationship with a non-Christian. There is some debate as to whether or not a Christian should date a non-Christian, but that has nothing to do with the question at hand, so we will set that aside.
So, if Christians shouldn't marry non-Christians, can the Christian at least ask God to reveal himself to the non-Christian so that they might receive Christ. The Bible is clear on this point, praying for the salvation of others is always something that is acceptable, and even encouraged by God. Luke 19:10 says Jesus

is come to seek and to save that which was lost.

Jesus himeslf came for the purpose of saving the lost, further, 1 Tomothy 2:4 says

Who will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth.

It is Christs desire that all people receive salvation, and in praying for their salvation, or that God will reveal themself to them, and show them their need of Him is only praying for what God already wants. Christ calls all men to himself, and certainly approves when we pray for others in this way. 1 Timothy 2:1,3;

I exhort therefore, that, first of all, supplications, prayers, intercessions, and giving of thanks, be made for all men...For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour;

God calls all of us to pray for everyone, saved and unsaved, and what better way to pray for the unsaved than to pray for their salvation. Its only natural for us to desire the salvation of those we care about, and praying for it is an excellent thing to do. The Bible certainly approves of this kind of prayer.
Finally, I wanted to say that besides praying for the unsaved we are also called to witness to them. Mark 16:15:

And he said unto them, Go ye into all the world, and preach the gospel to every creature.

Praying for the salvation of those we love is a good thing to do, but it would be even better to allow God to use you to bring them to salvation. Throughout the Bible there are countless admonitions to share the gospel with others, and oftentimes the unsaved are more receptive to the message of salvation when it comes from someone they care about.
In summary: The simple answer to your question is yes, the Bible certainly approves of this kind of prayer, and even encourages it. Praying for the salvation of others is something every Christian should take part in. But, we are also called to share the gospel with others, and this is even better than simply praying for them.

@budgie5434 your prayers are not the subject of the conversation.

You can and should pray for disbelievers or people of other religions; but you should realise that God gave human beings free will, and does not, generally speaking, override our free will to do His will. If He did, then we would never sin. So you can and should pray for her, but you should be aware that she may or may not convert, though you should hope and pray that she will. And if this relationship does not work our (I hope it does work out, but if it does not), you should remember for next time that dating non-Christians is a bad idea, a lesson I have learned myself.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
